# Is there a tool to manage resource of multiple resource and multiple configuration?

Tags: configuration, localization

I want a tool to manage my resource for multiple language and multiple configuration like a localizer. it may support '.rc' file and .net resource '.resx' file.

for example, I have a .rc file, I need four configuration for 'A' product, 'B' product, 'C' product, 'D' product, need two language 'English', 'French', then I need eight .rc file.

If I use the Localizer tool， I can Maintain four .rc file and a translate project to translate the four product file to multiple language.

Is there a tool to manage only one rc file and then Have a different configuration like translate file to auto build the eight target?

Comment: No one give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try Sisulizer which has a trial version. There is also RC WinTrans but it's expensive.

Comment: what i need is not a localizer tool, but a config file manage tool  like localizer